# Неправильно работает функция

Tags: javascript

```js
var transliterate = (
  function() {
    var rus = "щ   ш  ч  ц  ю  я  ё  ж  ъ  ы  э  а б в г д е з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ь".split(/ +/g),
      eng = "shh sh ch cz yu ya yo zh `` y' e` a b v g d e z i j k l m n o p r s t u f x `".split(/ +/g);
    var rus_char = "й ц у к е н г ш щ з х ъ ф ы в а п р о л д ж э я ч с м и т ь б ю".split(/ +/g),
      eng_char = "q w e r t y u i o p [ ] a s d f g h j k l ; ' z x c v b n m , .".split(/ +/g);
    return function(text, engToRus, bool, trans = true) {
      var x;
      for (x = 0; x < rus.length; x++) {
        text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x] : rus[x]).join(engToRus ? rus[x] : eng[x]);
        text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x].toUpperCase() : rus[x].toUpperCase()).join(engToRus ? rus[x].toUpperCase() : eng[x].toUpperCase());
        if (bool) text = text.split(trans ? eng_char[x] : rus_char[x]).join(trans ? rus_char[x] : eng_char[x]);
      }
      return text;
    }
  }
)();
console.log(transliterate("ьщдщвсщм", true, true, false));
console.log(transliterate("кщпщ", true, true, false));
```

Данный код неправильно переводит `ьщдщвсщм`, результат должен быть `molodcov`, а на деле получается `mололcоv`. Кто подскажет, где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: что значат параметры `bool` и `trans`?

Comment: а чем отличаются engToRus и trans? и кто такой bool? за что отвечает?
 и может быть стоит разбить одностроковые мутанты тернарников в нормальные строки ?

Comment: параметр `bool` отвечает за перевод абракадабры, по типу `ьщдщвсщм` или `fhntv`, а `trans` с какого языка переводить. Если с русского, то значение `false`.

Comment: а engToRus  тогда за что отвечает, если trans  - это с русского или не русского?

Comment: `engToRus` отвечает за точный перевод, учитывая `русская ж равна zh`, `bool` упускает же эти точности

Comment: Не знаю, будет ли кто-то копаться в этом коде, который чуть ли не минифицирован. Всё же советую его разбить и сделать более внятным и читаемым. Однако что я тут вижу, так это то, что ты зачем-то цикл устраиваешь по массиву `rus` вместо того, чтобы разбить как-раз таки **сам текст** на символы и уже бежать по нему, заменяя по условию буквы..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо за совет, учту!

Comment: Ошибка в логике: сначала ты английского на русский, потом с русского на английский. В итоге на одной из итераций попадается момент, когда ты переводишь уже переведенные символы.

Comment: @Grundy, да я это уже заметил. Но все равно спасибо!

Comment: Лучше вообще разделить функцию на две, тогда не будет такой проблемы

Comment: @Grundy учту, сейчас мне важно было получить результат и понять алгоритм, далее код будет подвергнут полному рефакторингу.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему тем, что доработал условие:

```
if (bool) {
      text = text.split(trans ? eng_char[x] : rus_char[x]).join(trans ? rus_char[x] : eng_char[x]);
} else {
      text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x] : rus[x]).join(engToRus ? rus[x] : eng[x]);
      text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x].toUpperCase() : rus[x].toUpperCase()).join(engToRus ? rus[x].toUpperCase() : eng[x].toUpperCase());
}
```

```js
var transliterate = (
  function() {
    var rus = "щ   ш  ч  ц  ю  я  ё  ж  ъ  ы  э  а б в г д е з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ь".split(/ +/g),
      eng = "shh sh ch cz yu ya yo zh `` y' e` a b v g d e z i j k l m n o p r s t u f x `".split(/ +/g);
    var rus_char = "й ц у к е н г ш щ з х ъ ф ы в а п р о л д ж э я ч с м и т ь б ю".split(/ +/g),
      eng_char = "q w e r t y u i o p [ ] a s d f g h j k l ; ' z x c v b n m , .".split(/ +/g);
    return function(text, engToRus, bool, trans = true) {
      var x;
      for (x = 0; x < rus.length; x++) {
        if (bool) {
          text = text.split(trans ? eng_char[x] : rus_char[x]).join(trans ? rus_char[x] : eng_char[x]);
        } else {
          text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x] : rus[x]).join(engToRus ? rus[x] : eng[x]);
          text = text.split(engToRus ? eng[x].toUpperCase() : rus[x].toUpperCase()).join(engToRus ? rus[x].toUpperCase() : eng[x].toUpperCase());
        }
      }
      return text;
    }
  }
)();
console.log(transliterate("ьщдщвсщм", true, true, false));
console.log(transliterate("кщпщ", true, true, false));
```

Теперь работает как надо.